# Is it necessary to try-catch every context.SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, entity-framework-core

MSDN says in order to resolve concurrency conflicts, one should use the following code:

```
using (var context = new PersonContext())
{
    // Fetch a person from database and change phone number
    var person = context.People.Single(p => p.PersonId == 1);
    person.PhoneNumber = "555-555-5555";

    // Change the person's name in the database to simulate a concurrency conflict
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "UPDATE dbo.People SET FirstName = 'Jane' WHERE PersonId = 1");

    var saved = false;
    while (!saved)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempt to save changes to the database
            context.SaveChanges();
            saved = true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            foreach (var entry in ex.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is Person)
                {
                    var proposedValues = entry.CurrentValues;
                    var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

                    foreach (var property in proposedValues.Properties)
                    {
                        var proposedValue = proposedValues[property];
                        var databaseValue = databaseValues[property];

                        // TODO: decide which value should be written to database
                        // proposedValues[property] = <value to be saved>;
                    }

                    // Refresh original values to bypass next concurrency check
                    entry.OriginalValues.SetValues(databaseValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException(
                        "Don't know how to handle concurrency conflicts for "
                        + entry.Metadata.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to wrap every instance of SaveChanges() that modify or add 
to the database inside the try-catch? Since it can potentially happen to a every instance of SaveChanges().

Comment: This is something only you can answer, and it depends on how you define "necessary". It's not absolutely *required* - your code will compile and run without it. But if your application will have records that will likely be modified by multiple users simultaneously, then you might choose that it's worth the effort.

Comment: If you'd need this check "all over the place" it would be more appropriate to deal with it in a SaveChanges override.